# Is there some mechanisms in PHP to assign "less trust" to scripts in a given dir?

Tags: php, security

I've attempted to ask this (in different ways) many times without ever getting a clear, real answer, nor even seem to be understood at all.

This has been a continuous worry and problem for me for ages:

For practical and logical reasons, I am forced to trust some **third-party PHP libraries**. These are installed, updated and managed with `Composer`, and live in `C:\PHP-untrusted-external`, entirely separated from my own PHP scripts, which live in `C:\PHP-my-own`.

The scripts in `C:\PHP-my-own` include and make use of the libraries in `C:\PHP-untrusted-external`.

Since there is no way that anyone, especially not I, could ever vet all the third-party code, and all updates, I'm looking for some way to "secure" or "sandbox" these in some way, even if it's just partial.

Basically, I'm worried that one day, an update will make an edit such as:

```
unlink('C:\');
```

Or:

```
phone_home_to_hacker_server($contents_of_my_harddrive);
```

If that happened, the scripts would happily run and do those actions. Nothing prevents them from doing so.

Is there really no way to specify in the `php.ini` configuration file, something like:

```
security.sandbox_dir = "C:\PHP-untrusted-external"
```

Or:

```
security.refuse_network_connections_for_dir = "C:\PHP-untrusted-external"
security.refuse_disk_io_for_dir = "C:\PHP-untrusted-external"
```

... or *something* like that?

I don't understand **Docker**. I have tried it countless times, and it makes no sense whatsoever to me. I don't want Docker. I don't want to deal with containers. Correction: I **can't** deal with it. I've tried to, but didn't understand it. Several times.

I just want PHP to support this in itself, and it seems more than reasonable to me. Doesn't it seem reasonable to you?

The saying that "at some point, you have to trust other people" is way too generic/vague to apply here. It's bypassing the problem. I don't trust people at all, and for good reason. It seems idiotic that we are (apparently) just supposed to sit around and wait for the disaster to happen. At least if I could prevent the third-party scripts form doing anything with the file system and network, that would go some way toward mitigating this issue. It still won't make the scripts unable to lie about the numbers/data they return to me, but at least they can't directly "phone home" or delete random files.

Comment: _I don't trust people at all, and for good reason._ The consequence of this is: *Do not ever use any code that you didn't wrote  yourself!*

Answer (score 0):

PHP does indeed provide these possibilities. Some extracts from php.ini:

```
; Directives following the section heading [PATH=/www/mysite] only
; apply to PHP files in the /www/mysite directory.

; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
; and below.  This directive makes most sense if used in a per-directory
; or per-virtualhost web server configuration file.
; http://php.net/open-basedir
;open_basedir =

; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names.
; http://php.net/disable-functions
;disable_functions = 

; This directive allows you to disable certain classes for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of class names.
; http://php.net/disable-classes
;disable_classes =
```

But these don't seem to be hacker-proof, let alone people you let install programs on your system.   I wonder how much easier you would have slept, all these ages, had you known about [Suhosin](https://suhosin.org/stories/index.html), or more recently [snuffleupagus](https://snuffleupagus.readthedocs.io/)